# Edit form creates new data instead php

Tags: php, mysql

im new to php, tried to 'google' the problem and it gave me nothing. I have index.php that has a form of creating new data and shows table data from sql with link on edit.php to edit data. In edit.php i have the form only.
So the problem is that edit.php creates new data in database instead of changing that one that i get by id. Tried to put request directly in phpmyadmin and everything worked fine.

edit.php

```
include '../connect.php';
include '../errors.php';
include 'view_edit.php';

var_dump($id = $_GET['edit']);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (empty($_POST['username'])){
    $errors = "Впишите ваше имя";
  }elseif (empty($_POST['email'])){
    $errors = "Впишите ваш email";
  }elseif (empty($_POST['task'])){
    $errors = "Впишите задание";
  }elseif (empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
    $errors = "Вставьте картинку";
  }else{
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $task = $_POST['task'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $target = "../uploads/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $sql = "UPDATE `tasks` SET `username`='$username', `email`='$email',
        `task`='$task', `image`='$image' WHERE `id`='$id'";
    mysql_query($db. $sql);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
    header('location: index.php');
  }
}
```

in `var_dump($id = $_GET['edit']);`  i get the correct id of data.

Form from view_edit.php

```
  <form method="post" action="index.php" class="input_form" enctype="multipart/form-
  data">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите Имя" 
  class="username_input">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите email" 
   class="email_input">
    <br>
    <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
  <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Введите задание" 
  class="task_input">
  <p>Сменить изображение</p>
  <input type="file" name="image" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg, 
  image/gif">
    <br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="add_btn">Изменить 
  запись</button>
  </form>
```

Table from index.php

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tasks)) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td class="username"> <?php echo $row['username']; ?> </td>
  <td class="email"> <?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
  <td class="task"> <?php echo $row['task']; ?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo "<img src='../uploads/".$row['image']."'>"; ?> </td>
    <td>
  <a class="delete" href="index.php?del_task=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">x</a>
    <br><br>
  <a class="edit" href="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?
     >">Редактировать</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <?php  } ?>
```

And form from view_index.php

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" class="input_form" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" 
 class="username_input" id="username">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш email" 
  class="email_input" id="email">
  <br><br>
<input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Введите задание" 
 class="task_input"  id="task">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
 <p>Добавить изображение</p>
<input type="file" name="image" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg, 
  image/gif">
 <br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="add_btn">Добавить задачу</button>
<button type="submit" name="preview" id="preview">Предварительный 
 просмотр</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked if `$_POST['edit_task']` exists and has a value?

Comment: @Michel    i tried this and i get NULL

Comment: Then `if (isset($_POST['edit_task'])){` will always fail and will never update. Check in your form if you have an input field with the name `edit-task`, if not create one.

Comment: @Michel i changed value of button to submit and `$_POST['submit']` still has no value but still creates new table row with data on index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some code in form `action` in `view_edit.php` and always use input submit button of form not

```
<form method="post" action="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="input_form" enctype="multipart/form-
      data">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите Имя"
               class="username_input">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите email"
               class="email_input">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
        <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Введите задание"
               class="task_input">
        <p>Сменить изображение</p>
        <input type="file" name="image" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg, 
      image/gif">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="edit_task" id="add_btn"
value="Изменить запись"/>
```

Remove `include 'view_edit.php';` from **edit.php** and use this code and tell me what happens

Comment: i tried to do that, and after clicking the submit button no data added to db i have NULL in `var_dump($_GET['edit']);` and in url [../edit.php?edit=] instead of [../edit.php?edit=16] 16 is and id and it changes if i chose other task(article) i also get fatal - Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in edit.php on line 39.
`37  $sql = "UPDATE `tasks` SET  `username`='$username',`email`='$email',
 38   `task`='$task', `image`='$image' WHERE `id`='$id'";
 39     mysql_query($db. $sql);` 

i tried to put query to phpmyadmin and it was fine

Comment: What is the url  when you click form submit button?

Comment: No, I asked for `view_edit.php` where form is deployed

Comment: `<form method="post" action="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="input_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Kindly tell me directory of `view_edit` and `edit.php`

Comment: zada4/admin/edit.php?edit= same thing for `view_edit.php`

Comment: ohh sorry plz, my eng is not that good.
zada4/admin/view_edit.php and zada4/admin/view.php

Comment: Ok,, Do some change in `index.php`. Replace `<a class="edit" href="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?
     >">Редактировать</a>` to `<a class="view_edit" href="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?
     >">Редактировать</a>`

Comment: Just do that and tell me

Comment: Ohh sorry replace it with `<a class="view_edit" href="view_edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ? >">Редактировать</a>`

Comment: Oh No!,, Show me your code screen shots then I will be able to tell you what the problem

Comment: it was a synt error here in edit.php `mysql_query($db. $sql);` needed to use comma now i get   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by [output started../view_edit.php:18] `form method="post" action="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $id; ?>"`  in ../edit.php on line 41 `header('location: edit.php');`. Also tried to change location to view_edit.php. In `var_dump($_POST['submit']);` after clicking button i get string(0).

Answer (score 0):

The action-attribute of your view_edit.php form is set to index.php, so unless edit.php gets included in the index.php, the submitted form won't be handled by edit.php but by index.php.

Anyway, an UPDATE query in MySQL can't create a new record, so the insertion must happen somewhere else in some code that is not posted here.

On a sidenote: Your code in very insecure. Google SQL-injection. People could use that form to drop your database or cause some other kind of harm.